# sql orcale query for comparing prices in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, inner-join

I need help with a basic Query. I've been given the tables and i need to find the following:

"List the names of people who sold products for the price higher than asking"
"Find the names of customer who sold the lowest number of product"

Here are the tables:

Table Customer

```
CID CNAME
--- ----------
```

Table People

```
PID ENAME SALARY MID
--- -------------------
```

Table Product

```
POID ATITLE     ARTIST      PRICEASKING
--- ---------- ----------- ----------
```

Table Makes

```
POID PID CID PRICESOLD 
--- --- --- ----------
```

Lets assume there is data in those tables. How do I figure out the query I wrote earlier. Here is what I have:

```
select PID from Makes where (select PRICESOLD from MakesD where POID IN (select POID from Makes)) > (select PRICEASKING from Product where POID IN (select POID from Makes));
```

Comment: If you're using oracle, don't tag MySQL (and vice versa)

Comment: And if a 'professor' prohibits the use of joins, I'd be tempted to find a different professor

Answer (score 0):

If you want all `makes` where the `pricesold` is greater than the `priceaksing` of the corresponding `product`, along with the `name` of the corresponding `people`, you can use joins:

```
select ma.*, pe.ename
from makes ma
inner join people pe on pe.pid = ma.pid
inner join product pr on pr.poid = ma.poid
where ma.pricesold > pr.priceasking
```

If you just want the names of persons that had at least one such make, then you can use `exists`:

```
select pe.ename
from people pe
where exists (
    select 1
    from makes ma
    inner join product pr on pr.poid = ma.poid
    where ma.pricesold > pr.priceasking and pe.pid = ma.pid
)
```

If you want to phrase this without any join (which, in my opinion, does not make the query simpler nor more efficient), then you can use a correlated subquery to recover the `priceasking` of the `product` (this works properly as long as `poid` is a unique key in `product`):

```
select pe.ename
from people pe
where exists (
    select 1
    from makes ma
    where 
        e.pid = ma.pid
        and ma.pricesold > (select pr.priceasking from product pr where pr.poid = ma.poid)
)
```

Comment: Hey, I am not alloweed to use inner join. Can't I use simple statements?

Comment: @user372204: this is simpler done with joins than with other techniques. Why wouldn't you use joins here?

Comment: Unfornunately, I am not allowed too :/  Professor don't want it lol

Comment: Saw it but the query doesn;t seem to return the lowest number of painting? It return, who sold at least one which is not what i want :/

Comment: @user372204: this answers this part of your question: *List the names of people who sold products for the price higher than asking*.

Comment: ouu okay any idea on how to get started on the other one?

Comment: @user372204: a StackOverflow question should contain just one question. You might want to ask another question, providing the relevant information, and showing your current attempt.

Comment: Aiit boss. Let me get on it